# How to fix delay (latency) of my OPENCV stream

Tags: c++, opencv, stream, lag

I have an IP camera which streams a rtsp
The follow code allows me to show the rtsp stream

```
int main(int, char**) {
    cv::VideoCapture vcap;
    cv::Mat image;

    const std::string videoStreamAddress = "rtsp://my_rtspstream";

    //open the video stream and make sure it's opened
    if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for(;;) {
        if(!vcap.read(image)) {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            cv::waitKey();
        }
        cv::imshow("Output Window", image);
        if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that i have about 450-600 ms of delay difference between what is the camera seeing and what i have o the window of opencv, and i need less becouse is camera with pt control.

Do you have any aproach? I should use another thing instead opencv??

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you check from where the latency is coming from, i.e. is the .read causing the problem or the imshow?

Comment: I think that the problem comes from the .read() . Becouse i have implemented the same code and then showed it with a WPF app (getting the cv::Mat frames) and i have the same delay.

Comment: okay, well maybe it is the allocation of memory to the cv::Mat.  Try allocating at the top globally, then use  <<  overload to read.  Otherwise i'm afraid you may have to step through/profile the read function, i suspect it will have many checks that you could bypass knowing your cap setup.